# Pyspark dataframe saving incorrectly to parquet?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm running into a perplexing problem when saving a dataframe to a parquet file after performing a series of transformations.

After I run a series of transformation steps, I check that the final dataframe is correct by checking the size and for duplicates.

```
result_df.count()

213051

result_df.select(count_distinct("RECORD_ID")).show()
+-------------------------+
|count(DISTINCT RECORD_ID)|
+-------------------------+
|                   213051|
+-------------------------+
```

I then write the dataframe to parquet using the API

```
result_df.write.parquet('path')
```

The issue arrises when I try and read the processed data later

```
processed_df = spark.read.parquet('path') 
processed_df.count()

213051

processed_df.select(count_distinct("RECORD_ID")).show()
+-------------------------+
|count(DISTINCT RECORD_ID)|
+-------------------------+
|                     6659|
+-------------------------+
```

Anyone have an idea about why this may be occuring and why duplicates are being introduced into the dataframe when saving? I'm not sure if there is an option when saving the dataframe that I am missing that would correct this behavior. I've checked the final df multiple times for duplicates and incorrect data but it alway looks good until I save it and reload it.

The cluster is a driver + 3 workers on Azure Databricks(Spark 3.2.1) if that is helpful.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I've been able to narrow down the issue to a dataframe I join on to the main dataframe in the transformation steps. The df in question is comprised of a file_name column and then a raw_text column which comprises of a large string for each row.

For reference, I'm already running the following UDF to help with non ascii characters:

```
def ascii_ignore(x):
    return x.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')

ascii_udf = udf(ascii_ignore)
```

Is this an issue with the parquet file not being able to interpret special characters and thus overwriting rows with the previously good rows?

Comment: Have you tried different path to save and load once

Comment: @AnjaneyaTripathi Yes, I have tried saving to 2 different mounted drives and still get the same issue.

Comment: Then rather than assuming duplicates are being introduced, I feel its a case of truncated /missing data as the overall count is still the same so can you try except once to see which distinct records are present in the first df but not present in distinct of the second df